# How come ballerina rotate so fast when there is no external force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

The question is **where are they getting this torque ($\tau$) thats causing them to increase their angular acceleration ($\alpha$) and therefore increasing their angular velocity ($\omega)?$**

Assuming it's frictionless ground(like on ice)

Comment: Are you sitting in an office chair right now? Make some room around youself, then give a push with your legs and stick them out as far as you can (or get someone to spin you with your legs stuck out)..Now while you're spinning, pull your legs in so your knees are bent and your feet are under the seat, near the post

Comment: @CaiusJard ... and then fall down miserably after having been ejected from your seat as my physics teacher once did, showing us exactly that. He intended to go the other way round (starting with arms and legs close to the body and decelerate) but got interrupted, mixed things up and bam.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They initially kick the ground and receive an equal and opposite force from it (Newton III), that's where the initial torque comes from. They would not be able to get this from a frictionless surface.

Then, to spin *even faster*, they usually move their arms close to their chest. This decreases their moment of intertia ($I$) and hence increases their angular velocity ($\omega$), following conservation of angular momentum $L = I\omega$.

Comment: "They give themselves an initial spin" this is misleading - the initial spin comes from the ground

Comment: @SeñorO Rephrased.

Comment: It looks like you got an answer, but I thought his question was "where does the $\alpha$ come from that takes the ice skater from one $\omega$ to a larger $\omega$." In that case, since angular momentum is conserved, then during the process where the ice skater draws their arms in, $\dot{I} \omega + I \alpha = 0$ which does not require an external torque.

Comment: Unlike an ice skater, a ballerina has to keep kicking the floor every couple of rotations, because there's a decent amount of friction.

Comment: @Barmar: Even ice skating can have a decent amount of friction.  You hold the skate blade at an angle to the direction you're pushing, so that the edge digs in a bit.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, but when the skater is spinning  they get onto the tip of the skate to minimize the friction -- they use the friction when they want to stop.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Ballerina, ice skater, whatever. Regardless, the point I'm trying to make is for the ideal case which is frictionless. The author already specified to assume everything is frictionless. Therefore, I thought the question was more along the lines of "Where does the $\alpha$ come from if there is no torque on the ballerina/skater?"

Comment: @SeñorO A new question has popped up in my mind, if there's external force acting on the system and the system converts this external force into torque then does that make it external torque? if yes then how can angular momentum be conserved? in this case this is what i'm seeing as she twists her ankle then this 'external force' by ground is converted into torque

Comment: @Rambalheartremo If it's external force, angular momentum is not conserved. But if there is no external force, see my answer below, I explicitly talk about the forces that accelerate the rotation. I haven't written out the computations yet, will add them when I have time.

Comment: @Rambalheartremo first of all, external vs. internal is entirely up to how you define it. If you consider the earth external, then yes it's an external torque. The combined angular momentum of the skater and earth around the skater's midline is conserved in this case (giving the earth a tiny rotation about that axis)

Answer (score 7):

For those who are equation-minded, I think one of the comments in this thread gave away the key Newtonian trick here, and I think the question stems from a misconception about Newton's second law.

Usually, we phrase Newton's second law(s), ignoring the nitty-gritty of vector stuff, as
$$
F_\text{net} = ma = m\frac{dv}{dt}\qquad \text{and}\qquad  \tau_\text{net} = I\alpha = I\frac{d\omega}{dt}
$$
... which, for rigid bodies, apply to the centre of mass of the object, or for systems of point masses, apply to their centre of mass. By "net", we mean the net sum over all interactions with masses not part of the body or system. Clearly, when the ballerina (or ice skater) goes to spin faster, her $\omega$ changes, so $d\omega/dt\neq 0$, and since $I\neq 0$, you would suspect $\tau_\text{net}\neq0$ by some magical ground interaction.

But actually, the above equations are only true in a limited sense: when mass and moment of inertia don't change in time (which is a safe assumption made in your typical high-school mechanics riddle). In Newton's full second law, the derivative is taken for the entire right-hand side, not just (angular) velocity. Hence:
$$
F_\text{net} = \frac{d(mv)}{dt} = \frac{dp}{dt} \qquad \text{and}\qquad  \tau_\text{net} = \frac{d(I\omega)}{dt} = \frac{dL}{dt}
$$
Aha! We can now live with $\tau_\text{net} = 0$, because that simply means
$$
0 =\frac{dL}{dt}\quad\iff\quad 0 =\frac{d(I\omega)}{dt}\quad\iff\quad 0 =\frac{dI}{dt}\omega + I\frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{dI}{dt}\omega + I\alpha
$$
which yields
$$
I\alpha = -\,\frac{dI}{dt}\omega.
$$
Let's assume we're spinning in the direction that $\omega>0$ (so, to speed up, $\alpha>0$). Also, just like mass, $I >0$. This equation tells us the full story that we see in the ballerina or ice skater: when she speeds up, $\alpha>0$, so the left-hand side is completely positive. What must she do to achieve this? Make the right-hand side completely positive, which only happens when $-dI/dt > 0$, or in other words, *when she decreases her moment of inertia*, e.g. by pulling in her arms and legs. No external torques or forces needed when already spinning ($\omega>0$)!

Comment: hold on i have question when she kicks the ground and twists her leg then she gets intial torque she needed, what you did there suggests $\Delta\tau= 0$ on the system, but i'm confused when she kicks the ground she's getting force from ground that means external force is being applied on the system and she's converting it into torque, that means angular momentum is variable?, how is the angular momentum is being conserved? $L=I\omega$ if $L$ is constant then we can say that when her moment of inhertia decreases when she brings her arms close, to account for decrease in $I$, $\omega$ will rise

Comment: I don't know what you're asking exactly (I never used $\Delta\tau$, e.g.), but here's what I think you need for an answer: in the general case, as specified above,
$$\tau_\text{net} =\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{dI}{dt}\omega + I\alpha.$$
So, when the ballerina interacts with the ground, the size of her angular momentum $L$ increases, because the ground system applies a torque on the ballerina system. Indeed, this can change $\omega$ and $\alpha$. Once she is spinning, she can *also* change $\omega$ and $\alpha$ (and $I$), but now, there's only one way to do it, namely as I described ($\tau = 0$).

Answer (score 5):

They push off the ground to get their angular momentum.

The ground is actually **far** from frictionless in this regard - it's only (mostly) frictionless in the direction parallel to the blades of their skates. They'd have a much harder time spinning if they were in street shoes.

Comment: Ballerina do wear shoes.  I think you're thinking of figure skaters.

Comment: @J... same difference though, and the OP did say "on ice".. Probably a hair that didn't need splitting...

Comment: @J... I see - so either "thats why ice skaters don't wear street shoes" or "thats why ballerinas don't perform on ice", take your pick ;)

Comment: @SeñorO there is such a thing as [Ballet on Ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_theatre)...

Comment: @Ruslan they wear skates. Skates = spin on ice. Shoes = hard to spin on ice.

Answer (score 2):

We assume no friction once the object is rotating.

When you rotate with stretched arms (kicked off by the ground, say), you have a rotational momentum. Without friction, that value stays constant, even if you bring the arms close. However, the rotational energy goes up during this process.

To bring the arms close you have to use force against the centrifugal force over the distance you need to cover bringing the arms closer to your body. This work is injected into the rotational energy of the body and causes this to go up.

If you compute the amount of work required to bring the outer masses closer to the rotational axis, you will find that it precisely matches the gain in rotational energy.

The torque required is the effect of a Coriolis-type force exerted on the masses when you move them closer to the rotational axes.

Disclaimer: I have computed that the rotational energy difference and confirm that it matches precisely the work exerted against the centrifugal force; however, I have not yet confirmed computationally that the Coriolis forces match the torques required to speed up the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Torque increases an object's angular momentum, not its angular velocity. If an object has a constant moment of inertia, then increasing one means increasing the other, but in this case, the ballerina drawing their arms in is decreasing their moment of inertia, and so their angular velocity can increase without increasing their angular momentum.